# module vs. dist share directories

Tags: perl, filesystems, perl-module

What is the difference between the usages of the `dist` and `module` directories located in `auto/share` in the Perl module installation directories? The [File::Share](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aShareDir) module documentation talks about both of them, but I don't really see a difference in expected usage. Since modules always come in distributions, they seem like the same thing to me. Furthermore, the [shareDir](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/Dist-Zilla-4.300029/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/ShareDir.pm) dzil plugin only installs the stuff into the `dist` directory, which seems like the more difficult of the two choices because now I have to either store the name of my distribution or do `__PACKAGE__ =~ s/::/-/g` to get the name of the share directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since modules always come in distributions, they seem like the same thing to me.*

its a logical separation, modules aren't distributions, modules can be moved

take for example libwww-perl distribution ( which doesn't use sharedir :)
it has many modules, and in the past few years they many of those many modules were each split into its own distribution

if these modules used dist_dir, each would require more editing

But if they used module_dir, no editing would be required for this issue

*Furthermore the shareDir dzil plugin  ...*

Make a bug report :)